# What is the benefit and micro-ops of ENQCMD instruction?

Tags: linux, x86, linux-device-driver, intel

[`ENQCMD`](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/ENQCMD) and [`MOVDIR64B`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movdir64b) are two instructions in Intel DSA.

> `MOVDIR64B` reads 64-bytes from the source memory address and performs a 64-byte direct-store operation to the destination address. The `ENQCMD` instruction allows software to write commands to enqueue registers, which are special device registers accessed using memory-mapped I/O (MMIO).

My question is - what is the aim of designing those two instructions?

Based on my understanding, setting up the memory-mapped IO area (the register) requires OS support, i.e. the device driver. After setting up the MMIO area, we could access it using `write()` system call, which is also implemented in the device driver. For general architectures, Linux supports `iowrite64()` to write 8-byte values at a time. Hence, if we want to write 64 bytes, needs to call `iowrite64()` 8 times.

With the help of `MOVDIR64B`, for Intel DSA, a [new API](https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/157428502934.36836.8119026517510193201.stgit@djiang5-desk3.ch.intel.com/) is created - `__iowrite512()` which writes 64 bytes atomically.

I agree that the latter one is at least more efficient than the previous one, but I am confused about the time it requires to transfer data.

Consider the following case: if we are given a device (Intel DSA) that supports `MOVDIR64B` and `ENQCMD`, suppose we want to transfer 64 bytes of data from memory to MMIO register. There are two options: `iowrite64()` 8 times (using a loop); or `__iowrite512()` once. Will the latter one be 8 times faster than the previous one?

My thoughts is that it is less likely to be 8 times difference, but the latter one will be faster. May I know how faster it would be? Is it documented anywhere? I do not have Intel DSA, so I am not sure how to test it.

Besides, what other benefits do `ENQCMD` have? Will it be broken up into several micro operations? If yes, then what are the micro operations that does `ENQCMD`?

Comment: https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Linux-Make-Use-Of-ENQCMD explains the same thing @prl did: that ENQCMD returns a status while MOVDIR64B doesn't, so you don't have to do more I/O to check stuff.  (Interesting point about that enabling shared work queues).  See also https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Intel-ENQCMD-In-TIP - apparently Linux's ENQCMD support was disabled because it was buggy, but got fixed in Feb. of this year.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @prl. I am thinking about the latency of such instruction. For instance, how many cycles is required to transfer the 64 bytes of data. Would it be the same as transferring 8 bytes only? If yes, then ENQCMD and MOVDIR64B increase the bandwidth of data movement, which is one benefit over other types of I/Os.

Comment: @prl - I am a bit confused about the word "serialized". Does it mean the next 8-byte write cannot start until the previous one finished? Similarly, you mentioned that __iowrite512 allows the descriptor to arrive at the device all at once, instead of in pieces. Does that mean the time for iowrite64() * 8 will take 8 times longer than __iowrite512? It seems that it simplifies the design of device, but what I would like to focus on is how much faster it would be from the user's perspective.

Comment: @prl: In case I did not explain clearly. The aim of those two instructions is to improve performance, and make work submission "scale". I would like to know more about the detail of how it improves the performance. For instance, by using the same time but transferring much more data (64 bytes at once) than before? Or, by decreasing the software complexity to manage the work queues? May I know what is the main contribution to the **performance increase**? Note: for most materials I found, they all mention virtualization, i.e. targeting datacenters, which oversimplifies performance aspect.

Comment: @prl: Thanks for your detailed reply. I also noticed in the doc that Intel DSA portal is a 4096-byte page. May I know if that means Intel DSA allows 64 descriptors to be submitted at the same time? Since there are multiple portals (as far as I remember, there are 4), so at most 64*4 = 256 submissions could be performed at the same time, right? In other words, does that mean Intel DSA supports 256 64-byte streaming (WC) writes at the same time? Feel free to correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @prl: I still have some more detailed questions about the work submission of Intel DSA regarding to the portals. Since that question is too long, I make it a new question which could be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72515486/how-does-intel-dsa-data-streaming-accelerators-bring-the-work-descriptor-fro. Feel free to take a look when you are free.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

iowrite64 uses a UC access to MMIO space, so writes are serialized, not pipelined. That is, only one UC write can be in flight at a time from a single CPU thread, and the CPU doesn't continue execution until the MMIO write is complete.

MOVDIR64B has the potential to be faster than even a single iowrite64, because it uses the WC memory type instead of UC (even if the destination address is UC). After the write is issued by the CPU, it can continue execution. Multiple direct stores can be streamed to the device. That means that multiple direct stores can be in flight at one time from a single CPU thread. MOVDIRI also behaves this way.

As far as I know, the time to actually transfer the data to the destination is the same regardless of the size (between 1 and 64 bytes). Of course that is dependent on the width of the data path within the SoC, which could be different for different implementations.

The main advantage of MOVDIR64B is that the descriptor arrives at the device all at once instead of in pieces. The device doesn't have to worry about receiving a partial descriptor or receiving parts of two descriptors interleaved. In fact, Intel DSA ignores writes smaller than 64 bytes to a portal.

To realize the full benefit of streaming writes, the destination address for each MOVDIR64B from a single CPU thread should be different. Each Intel DSA portal is a 4096-byte page, so there are 64 unique addresses within each portal. Descriptor writes from a single CPU can be striped across the 64 addresses. (It doesn't matter whether writes from multiple CPUs use the same address or different addresses, but normally you would not expect multiple CPUs to be using the same dedicated WQ in DSA.)

ENQCMD allows the device to respond to software whether it accepted the descriptor or not. This allows multiple applications to use the same shared WQ without risk of a descriptor being lost because the shared WQ is full. Applications can submit descriptors without any driver involvement (after setup), and without any lock or communication between the applications.